# What software is lock or lck

Tags: gnu-screen, screen-lock

Which software provides `/usr/bin/lock` or `/local/bin/lck` ?

The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Lock.html) says that GNU Screen will call a screenlock program. But I don't have them in my system. Also my `$LOCKPRG` is empty. So is there any standard Linux software which I can install that provides lock facility for GNU Screen ?

Comment: It's a fair Question, but I would be asking why you need this functionality. ISTM it would make more sense to be locking your client (ie your PC or Workstation) than individual screen sessions. Long gone are the days of green-screen terminals

Comment: @roaima Imagine I'm in a server room with GNU Screen running on it. `C-a x` sound is nice then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My edition of `screen` on Debian (package version 4.1.0~20120320) has lock functionality built-in; hitting `C-a x` locks the entire environment (so that not even detach with `C-a d` is permitted). The Debian version of the [man page for screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) writes, "Call a screenlock program (/local/bin/lck or /usr/bin/lock *or a builtin if no other is available*)."

If you want to lock a terminal session you can use `vlock`. From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/vlock), "vlock is a program to lock one or more sessions on the Linux console."

I also tried installing `vlock` and running `LOCKPRG=$(type -p vlock) screen`. After hitting `C-a x` to lock the screen I saw that `screen` was correctly calling `vlock` to lock the screen. Again, the entire environment was locked so I couldn't suspend screen with `C-a d`.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. But neither my user password nor root password is working for unlocking the screen locked by `vlock`.

Comment: @Sibi, `vlock` works for me. Next time you could try with the built-in lock functionality. Or test `vlock` directly rather than inside `screen`.

Comment: Yes, vlock doesn't work for me inside screen. But it works in a plain shell. I'm looking for something which works inside `screen`. The built-in lock facility of screen (invoked through C-a x) doesn't accept either of my or root's password for unlocking.

Comment: @Sibi you are using the account password for the system that started `screen`...?

Comment: Yes, I did try that initially. But that doesn't work. Does that work for you under `screen` ? Also root's password also doesn't work.

Comment: @Sibi yes both work for me